# how to uppercase multiple id (checkbox in php using javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

How to uppercase each j1 "click" then the f1 text change to uppercase, j2 "click" then the f2 text change to uppercase, et seq..

```
<table>
    <form>    
    <?      
         $i=0;
        foreach ($im as $row):
       $i++;
        ?>
         <tr>
                <td><? echo $i;?></td>
                <td><? echo $row['Something'] ?></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="j<? echo $i ?>" onclick="if(this.checked){myFunction()}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="f<? echo $i ?>" value="Test"></td>
                    </tr>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("f"+<? echo $i ?>).value = document.getElementById("f"+<? echo $i ?>).value.toUpperCase();
        }
        </script>
        <? endforeach; ?>
        </form>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value of `$i` to the function and use it to identify the element. Try with -

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="j<? echo $i ?>" onclick="if(this.checked){myFunction('<? echo $i ?>')}"></td>
```

And define the function -

```
    <script>
    function myFunction(i) {
        document.getElementById("f"+i).value = document.getElementById("f"+i).value.toUpperCase();
    }
    </script>
```

You dont have to put the function inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

for another option, you don't need to declare "id" attribute in input text element, you can use "name" attribute http://jsfiddle.net/j4080ytq/

```
<form>
<table>
    <?      
    $i=0;
    foreach ($im as $row):
    $i++;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $i;?></td>
        <td><? echo $row['Something'] ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked){f<? echo $i; ?>.value = f<? echo $i; ?>.value.toUpperCase();}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="f<? echo $i ?>" value="Test"></td>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</table>
</form>
```